# Ionic 4 Input Decorator with images

Tags: ionic-framework, input

I'm fairly new to ionic and I was wondering how to add images through an Input Decorator.
For the .html I had used :  , but I havent figured out what to insert in my .ts

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts file you may do like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    
@Input() myImage;
    
constructor(
){
}
    
ngOnInit() {
  this.myImage = 'assets/imgs/myImage.png';
}
```

}